# Add Form Fields Dynamically -- ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My requirement is to add form fields dynamically. I am able to add form group dynamically on click of button **+Add Heading**.

In that form group, I have a button **+Add Content** on click of which a new input element should be added to the group.

I am able to modify the JSON accordingly and logging the same and updating the state.
but my view is not rendering as expected.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-utjwsu?embed=1&file=index.js

/*Code for the same*/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Progress,Button } from 'reactstrap';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';


const byPropKey = (propertyName, value) => () => ({
    [propertyName]: value,
  });
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      Information:'',
      ImageUrl:'',
      isUploading: false,
      isUploaded: true,
      showProgress: false,
      progress: 0,
      avatarUrl:'',
      ref:'WhitePapersItems',
      formValid: false,
      content: [{Heading: "", Content: [{value:""}]}]
    };

        this.AddContentBox = this.AddContentBox.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.AddContentInput = this.AddContentInput.bind(this);
  }

  AddContentBox(){
        return this.state.content.map((element,i)=>(
            <div className="header-content" key={i} >
                <div className="heading-content-wrapper">
                <FormGroup>
                <Label className="set-label-pos upload-img" for="Heading">Heading</Label>
                <input className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}
                    type="text"/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                <Label className="set-label-pos upload-img" for="Heading">Content</Label>
                <input className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}
                    type="text"/>
                </FormGroup>
                {/* {this.AddContentInput} */}
                <FormGroup>
                <Button color="success" onClick={this.AddContentInput.bind(this,i)}>+ Add Content</Button>
                </FormGroup>
            </div>
            </div>
        ))
    }

    handleChange(i, e) {
    const { Heading, value } = e.target;
      let content = [...this.state.content];
      content[i] = {...content[i], [Heading]: value};
      this.setState({ content });
   }

   AddContentInput(index, val){
        console.log('Add ContentInput triggered',val,index);       
        const contents = this.state.content;
        contents[index].Content.push({value:''});
        this.setState({content:contents});
        const item = this.state.content[index].Content;
        console.log('item', item)
        return item.map((element, i)=>(
            <FormGroup>
               <Label className="set-label-pos upload-img" for="Heading">Content</Label>
               <input className="form-control" type="text"/>
           </FormGroup>
       ))

        // console.log(this.state)
        // this.addContentField(index);
    }

     addHeading(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState(prevState => ({ 
            content: [...prevState.content, { Heading: "", Content: [{value:""}] }]
        }))
        this.AddContentBox();
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>


        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

                <FormGroup>
                    <Label className="set-label-pos upload-img" for="Information">Information</Label>
                    <textarea className="form-control" rows="10" onChange={event => this.setState(byPropKey('Information', event.target.value))}
                        type="text"/>
                </FormGroup>
                {this.AddContentBox()}
                <div className="add-heading-button">
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.addHeading.bind(this)}>+ Add Heading</Button>
                </div>
                <FormGroup>
                <input type="hidden" value={this.state.ImageUrl} onChange={event => this.setState(byPropKey('ImageUrl', event.target.value))}/>
                </FormGroup>

                <Button className="btn btn-danger" size="lg" type="submit">+ Add White Papers Item</Button>
                </Form>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question for ones who might come across such scenarios.

Update my stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-utjwsu?embed=1&file=index.js

Instead of rendering all content field i was trying to render only one.

/*Code goes here*/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Progress,Button } from 'reactstrap';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';


const byPropKey = (propertyName, value) => () => ({
    [propertyName]: value,
  });
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      Information:'',
      ImageUrl:'',
      isUploading: false,
      isUploaded: true,
      showProgress: false,
      progress: 0,
      avatarUrl:'',
      ref:'WhitePapersItems',
      formValid: false,
      content: [{Heading: "", Content: [{value:""}]}]
    };

        this.AddContentBox = this.AddContentBox.bind(this);
        this.AddContentInput = this.AddContentInput.bind(this);
        //this.addContentTextBox = this.addContentTextBox.bind(this);
  }

  AddContentInputFields(element) {
    return element.Content.map(content => {
      return (
        <FormGroup>
          <Label className="set-label-pos upload-img" for="Heading">Content</Label>
          <input className="form-control" type="text"/>
        </FormGroup>
      );
    })
  }

  AddContentBox(){
        return this.state.content.map((element,i)=>(
            <div className="header-content" key={i} >
                <div className="heading-content-wrapper">
                <FormGroup>
                <Label className="set-label-pos upload-img" for="Heading">Heading</Label>
                <input className="form-control" type="text"/>
                </FormGroup>
                { this.AddContentInputFields(element) }
                <FormGroup>
                <Button color="success" onClick={this.AddContentInput.bind(this,i)}>+ Add Content</Button>
                </FormGroup>
            </div>
            </div>
        ))
    }

    handleChange(i, e) {
    const { Heading, value } = e.target;
      let content = [...this.state.content];
      content[i] = {...content[i], [Heading]: value};
      this.setState({ content });
   }

   AddContentInput(index, val){
        console.log('Add ContentInput triggered',val,index);       
        const contents = _.cloneDeep(this.state.content);
        contents[index].Content.push({value:''});

        const item = contents[index].Content;
        console.log('item', item);
        this.setState({content:contents});
        //this.addContentTextBox(item);

    }

    // addContentTextBox(item){
    //   return item.map((element, i)=>(
    //         <FormGroup>
    //            <Label className="set-label-pos upload-img" for="Heading">Content</Label>
    //            <input className="form-control" type="text"/>
    //        </FormGroup>
    //    ));
    // }

     addHeading(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState(prevState => ({ 
            content: [...prevState.content, { Heading: "", Content: [{value:""}] }]
        }))
        this.AddContentBox();
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>


        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

                <FormGroup>
                    <Label className="set-label-pos upload-img" for="Information">Information</Label>
                    <textarea className="form-control" rows="10" onChange={event => this.setState(byPropKey('Information', event.target.value))}
                        type="text"/>
                </FormGroup>
                {this.AddContentBox()}
                <div className="add-heading-button">
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.addHeading.bind(this)}>+ Add Heading</Button>
                </div>
                <FormGroup>
                <input type="hidden" value={this.state.ImageUrl} onChange={event => this.setState(byPropKey('ImageUrl', event.target.value))}/>
                </FormGroup>

                <Button className="btn btn-danger" size="lg" type="submit">+ Add White Papers Item</Button>
                </Form>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason this isn't working properly is because you are directly modifying `this.state`. React won't automatically re-render, because you didn't tell it that the state had changed.

You need to be calling `this.setState()` to set the new state.

If you are adding to an object (such as `this.state.content`, you need to make sure that you take a copy of the object (using something like `_.cloneDeep()`) to make sure you are not modifying the existing object.

Hopefully that is enough explanation for you to be able to fix your problem.

UPDATE: 
You are indirectly modifying the state, with this code:

    `const contents = this.state.content;
    contents[index].Content.push({value:''});`

`contents` is a variable which isn't a copy of `this.state.content`, it'a a reference to it. So pushing a value into the object is actually modifying the state directly. My apologies for not making this clearer in the original answer

Comment: I am not modifying state directly anywhere

Comment: looks like I am missing something

Comment: Try this - not sure if it's exactly what you were intending... https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9sesua?file=index.js

Comment: I just want to one more input box on click of add content button i.e. one heading and two content box

Comment: Although our array of Content is getting changed properly but not the view

Comment: Do you see you were not iterating over Content?

Comment: I am saving the current Content value in const item
and iterating on that

Comment: Let me know if you still need help

Comment: Yes I am still struggling with the same